# 2d array from a txt file into JavaFx(sudoku)

Tags: java, javafx, multidimensional-array, sudoku, txt

I want to load the date from the `sudoku3000.txt` file into my javafx interface over an Example button. Scann the sudoku3000.txt file into a 2d araay is working but im not sure how to override the textFiles with my new 2d array. Thanks for help!

this is my `MyFxApp`:

```
TextField[][] textFields = new TextField[9][9];

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    //Insert the the text fields into the grid
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            TextField t = new TextField();
            t.setAlignment((Pos.CENTER));
            textFields[c][r] = t;
            grid.add(t, c, r);
        }
    }

  
    //This is the Example button that i want to override
    btn = new Button("Example");
    hBox = new HBox(10);
    hBox.getChildren().add(btn);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    grid.add(hBox, 3, 9, 3, 1);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            ImportText importT = new ImportText();
            for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
                    try {
                        int[][] newArray = importT.text();
                        newArray[c][r] = Integer.valueOf(textFields[c][r].getText().trim());
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

  

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

this is my `ImportText` class

```
public ImportText() {
}

public int[][] text() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/sudoku.txt")));
    int[][] myArray = new int[9][9];
        for (int c = 0; c < myArray.length; c++) {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int r = 0; r < line.length; r++) {
                myArray[c][r] = Integer.parseInt(line[r]);
            }

    }
    //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
    return myArray;
}
```

this is my sudoku.txt file

```
4 8 3 9 2 1 6 5 7
9 6 7 3 4 5 8 2 1
2 5 1 8 7 6 4 9 3
5 4 8 1 3 2 9 7 6
7 2 9 5 6 4 1 3 8
1 3 6 7 9 8 2 4 5
3 7 2 6 8 9 5 1 4
8 1 4 2 5 3 7 6 9
6 9 5 4 1 7 3 8 2
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the button is pressed?

Comment: ohh im sorry! i want to show the numbers in my sudoku grid

Comment: So in the event handler: 1. get the `int[][]` array from your import class, 2. iterate through it, and set the text of each text field to the corresponding value from the array. Right now you are loading the entire text file 81 times (why?????)